# remove a string and get whatever left on the right side

Tags: php, string, split, str-replace

I have strings occurring like

**Priv.-Doz. Dr. med. Susan. Andreas  Pailo**

**Dr. med. Sumat  Dagdelen**

**Prof. Dr. med. Sandrien  Axaigeler**

How can i remove "Dr. med." and get right side of string, in case one i'll get 'Susan. Andreas  Pailo' after removing Dr. med.

Question could be duplicate somewhere but didn't find after lots of try.

Please suggest,
thank you

Comment: have you tied str_replace?

Comment: Please provide your sample code

Comment: but using str_replace, i didn't get right side of strings. i also get left side of string, which i don't want.

Comment: where do these strings come from? Can you get the names without the title and honorary prefixes instead? That would be easier that using str_replace because with str_replace you will need to provide all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution using `substr` and `strpos` functions:

```
$str = "Priv.-Doz. Dr. med. Susan. Andreas  Pailo";
$seach_str = "Dr. med.";
echo substr($str, strpos($str, $seach_str) + strlen($seach_str));
// "Susan. Andreas  Pailo"
```

Answer (score 4):

To get right string after some string use `explode()` as

```
$data="Priv.-Doz. Dr. med. Susan. Andreas  Pailo";
$search="Dr. med.";
$result = explode($search, $data);
echo  end($result);//Susan. Andreas  Pailo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $str = 'Prof. Dr. med. Sandrien  Axaigeler';
 $str = str_replace("Dr. med.","",$str);
 $str = str_replace("Prof.","",$str);
 echo $str;
```

Comment: I get 'Prof.' also which i don't need.

Comment: i need only 'Sandrien  Axaigeler' in this case.

Comment: well this is somewhat useful, i then just need to find again fro prof. if any.

Answer (score 0):

Try using str_replace

```
$value = str_replace("Dr. med.","",$value );
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work.Search the word what you want separately.

```
 $string = 'Prof. Dr. med. Sandrien  Axaigeler';
 $string = str_replace("Dr. med.","",$string );
 $string = str_replace("Prof.","",$string );
 print_r($string);
```

Comment: i am also getting Prof. which i don't need.

Comment: so you can put searching value `Prof. Dr. med.` and replace with blank `string`.Or you can search with separately.

Comment: but if you look at my different cases, somewhere i am getting prof. and somewhere not. that create confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$str = 'Prof. Dr. med. Sandrien  Axaigeler';

$name_str = str_replace("Prof.","",$str);
$name_str = str_replace("Priv.-Doz.","",$name_str);
$name_str = str_replace("Dr. med.","",$name_str);
$name_str = trim($name_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume that you are asking to extract the part of the string **after** *Dr. med.*, and don't necessarily need to keep the rest of the string - including what's in front?

If yes, you can do the following:

1. Find the position of *Dr. med.* using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).
2. Extract the sub-string using [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) from the position found in step 1 in your $start argument.

An example could be like:

```
<?php
$InputString = "Priv.-Doz. Dr. med. Susan. Andreas  Pailo";
$PositionOfSearch = strpos($InputString, "Dr. med.");
$ExtractedString = substr($InputString, $PositionOfSearch);
?>
```

Though you might need to tweak the *$PositionOfSearch* value as PHP might return the position of the 'D' instead. You can add the length of the string you're searching for - *Dr. med.* - to *$PositionOfSearch*.

Unfortunately I don't have a production software in the computer I'm currently using, I'm unable to test for a working code for you, but hopefully this will set you off in some direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat longer and less performant, but you can easily add all title words you want to remove to the array `$titles_to_ignore`.

```
function remove_academic_titles($input) {
    $titles_to_ignore = ['Dr.', 'Prof.', 'med.', 'Priv.', 'Doz.'];

    foreach ($titles_to_ignore as $title) {
        $input = preg_replace("@". preg_quote($title) ."[-\s]*@", "", $input);
    }
    return $input;
}
$old = "Priv.-Doz. Dr. med. Susan. Andreas  Pailo";
$new = remove_titles($old);
```

Comment: you can also pass that array to `str_replace` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = "Priv.-Doz. Dr. med. Susan. Andreas  Pailo"
$resularray = explode("Dr. med.",$string);
```

echo $resularray[0];`

Comment: Please share your required result with snapshot.